Sub-domain Enumeration - socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
I am trying to do sub-domain enumeration in my organization. Part of the python code is to get the IPs of the already enumerated sub-domains which are included in a text file . Used the below code
import socket

file = open(r'C:\Users****\Downloads\sublist.txt')
domain_list = []
for x in file.readlines():
    domain_list.append(x.rstrip())
for y in domain_list:
    print(y + ' -> ' + socket.gethostbyname(y))

The script doesn't seem to work and giving me the error "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" when i included my organization's sub-domains in the txt file "sublist.txt". But it gives me the proper IP addresses when any other public domains are used in the list such as google.com
Note - simply running the command socket.gethostbyname('organization sub-domain name') gives me the proper result and I am connected via VPN to my org

socket.gaierror is an exception indicating name resolution failure.
Your domain name failed to be resolved into a v4/v6 address with the usual local (/etc/hosts ...) or distributed (DNS) mechanisms.
Seems that you are passing partially qualified domain names (like organization) instead of the fully qualified name (e.g. organization.com), which is what the DNS is able to recognize.

Hey igmartin , thanks for editing my question . coming to ur query I am passing the fully qualified domain name (organization.com and not just organization). Also I would like you know that the command socket.gethostbyname('organization sub-domain name') works as expected when ran separately in terminal but not in script

Hi. I have been diving into the code and gethostbyname() calls internally getaddrinfo()for resolution to IPv4 addresses only. This is why it says "... getaddrinfo failed"
The error you receive is Windows specific: errorTab[11001] = "Host not found."

Hi Igmartin, is there any workaround to this?

I would try getaddrinfo() instead of gethostbyname(). It might give you more information

A FQDN is not: "I used a dot." This is a common misnomer.
FQDN on some variants are strict, you must use a dot at the end... localhost. vs. localhost -> that's a PQDN on a bad day...
